# If $X$ is completely regular and $A\subset U\subset X$ is such that $A$ is compact, $U$ is open, there is $g:X\to [0,1]$

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ is completely regular and $A\subset U\subset X$ is such that $A$ is compact, $U$ is open, there is $g:X\to [0,1]$ such that $g(x) = 1$ for all $x\in A$ and $g(x) = 0, ~\forall x\in X - U.$

I know that if $x\in A$ then there is a function $f : X\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = 1 $ and $f(x) = 0$ on $X-U.$

But, how to choose a function that works on $A$ entirely?

Comment: Fix $0<\epsilon<1$ and let $B=X-U$. For each $x\in A$ there is a continuous function $f_x:X\rightarrow [0,1]$ satisfying $f_x(x)=0$ and $f_x(B)=1$. Define $U_x=f_x^{-1}([0,\epsilon))$. These sets cover $A$. Since $A$ is compact, there is a finite sub cover $U_{x_1},\ldots,U_{x_k}$. Define $f=\prod_{i=1}^k f_{x_i}$. Then $f(x)<\epsilon$ for all $x\in A$ and $f(B)=1$.  Find a continuous function $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ so that $g=\gamma\circ f$ satisfies $g(A)=0$ and $g(B)=1$.

Comment: As the maximum of two continuous functions is continuous, $\gamma(t)=\frac{\max\{t,\epsilon\}-\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}$ should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using complete regulariry of $X$ and compactness of $A$, construct open sets $(V_1, \dots, V_m)$ (finite sequence), covering $A,$ and continuous $[0,1]$-valued functions $(f_1, \dots, f_m)$ on $X$ such that $f_i(V_i)=0,\ f_i(X\setminus U)=1,\, i=1, \dots, m.$ Set $f=\prod_{i=1}^m f_i$ and $g=1-f.$